# Using Razor with Durandal gives 404

Tags: razor, durandal, single-page-application

i am trying to use cshtml with Durandal

i followed instructions on 
http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2014/03/durandaljs-enable-razor-views.html

main.js is called properly but when it goes looking for the view i get the error.

**View Not Found. Searched for "views/shell" via path "text!views/shell.cshtml".**

and in the console window i can see a 404 error

**http:// local   /App/views/shell.cshtml 404 (Not Found)**

route is configured and i copied the web.config from View to App/views and the DurandalViewController is also in place.
 my main.js looks like one in the example
just the last line is

```
 app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');
```

**__________________________________**

Structure has

- App/viewmodels/shell.js
- App/views/shell.cshtml
- App/views/web.config

Answer (score 0):

Your issue will be the routing in Asp.net.
Most likely the routing engine will be looking for shell.cshtml in `http://localhost/views/shared/shell.cshtml` or `http://localhost/views/yourControllerName/shell.cshtml` by default.  You will need to add a route to tell the server side where to find the view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

for info I had a similar issue.

Everything was working locally but when I deployed my solution to Azure Web sites I got an error: 
**Not Found. Searched for "views/shell" via path "text!views/shell.cshtml".**

In my case it was http error 500.

Solution was to rename a file from "shell" to something else. I renamed it to  base.cshtml (and base.js). It looks that somehow shell.cshtml could not be processed on Azure.